# PostGIS ST_Within returns zero data

Tags: postgis, postgresql, point-in-polygon

I am using PostgreSQL 9.3.3 & PostGIS 2.1.1 and I have a table Entries which has a column called "latlng" of geographic type (this column stores entry's latitude and longitude coordinates).

I am trying to find all entries that belong to a given polygon - like this:

```
entries = Entry.find_by_sql("
    SELECT *
    FROM Entries
    WHERE ST_Within(
        Entries.latlng::geometry,
        ST_GeomFromText(
            'POLYGON((
                #{swLat} #{swLng},
                #{swLat} #{neLng},
                #{neLat} #{neLng},
                #{neLat} #{swLng},
                #{swLat} #{swLng}))',
            4326)
    );")
```

Which translates into the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM Entries
WHERE ST_Within(
    Entries.latlng::geometry,
    ST_GeomFromText(
        'POLYGON((
            45.61490708797995 -121.32521530382634,
            45.61490708797995 -121.32338469617367,
            45.615492910571655 -121.32338469617367,
            45.615492910571655 -121.32521530382634,
            45.61490708797995 -121.32521530382634))',
        4326)
```

Even though I am sure that my table has entries that have coordinates that belong to such polygon, I get zero results back. Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have specified into your question, the coordinates must be expressed following the "latlng" order, therefore I suggest you to store the data in your table in the proper oder (the `longitude` **first** and the `latitude` **second**).

Using this logic, your second statement must be reformulated as below:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Entries
WHERE ST_Within(
    Entries.latlng::geometry,
    ST_GeomFromText(
        'POLYGON((
            -121.32521530382634 45.61490708797995,
            -121.32338469617367 45.61490708797995, 
            -121.32338469617367 45.615492910571655,
            -121.32521530382634 45.615492910571655,
            -121.32521530382634 45.61490708797995))',
        4326)
```

Also, you must to assure yourself your "latlng" colum is really of geometry type (for example a point). If this is you case, then you simply may specify the column name

```
latlng
```

instead of

```
Entries.latlng::geometry
```

But, if your "latlng" column looks like this:

```
POINT(-121.32 45.61)
```

then, you must use

```
ST_GeomFromText(latlng, 4326)
```